# (JDA) Mute command is breaking at the fourth line of the code

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

```
String[] messageSent = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
if (messageSent[0].equalsIgnoreCase("/mute")) {
            if (messageSent.length == 2) {
                Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(messageSent[1].replace("<@", "").replace(">", ""));
                Role role = event.getGuild().getRoleById("731166424608931900");

                if (!member.getRoles().contains(role)) {
                        //mute user
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Muted " + messageSent[1] + ".").queue();
                    event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(member, role);
                }else {
                    //unmute user
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Unmuted " + messageSent[1] + ".").queue();
                    event.getGuild().removeRoleFromMember(member, role);
                }

            }else if (messageSent.length == 3) {

            }else {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("incorrect syntax i dont have time to make this error message pretty, fuck!").queue();
            }
        }
```

so the problem with this is that

1st: it probably breaks at the fourth line aka  `Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(messageSent[1].replace("<@", "").replace(">", ""));`

2nd: i get this error `[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: yeah its 100% breaking at the fourth line, as it gets "null"
i saw it by printing out the result of `member` after i declared it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should just use [`Message#getMentionedUsers`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getMentionedUsers()) and let JDA do the parsing for you.
2. Make sure the Member is [cached](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy) or use [`Guild#retrieveMemberById`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#retrieveMemberById(long)) (or one of the other `retrieveMember*` methods) instead.

Edit: See also [Troubleshooting:
Users/Members not in cache](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19%29-Troubleshooting#usersmembers-not-in-cache)